# VS Code showing 'random' module overriding, how to solve it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, random, anaconda, importerror

[Check This Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIxgP.png) I imported the `random` module in Python and tried running it. It is imported and it is running good as well, but VSCode is giving a yellow line warning and showing that it is overriding with the module in `venv\Lib`. It is asking me to change the name of `random.py` to something else, which I can't change because it will give me errors in other libraries like pandas, numpy, matplotlib, and OpenCV. How can I remove this unwanted warning?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
"c:\Users\Syed M Tayyab\Desktop\VS Code ML\venv\Lib\random.py" is overriding the stdlib module "random"PylancereportShadowedImports
```

I tried changing random.py To something else but as I mentioned earlier that changing randon.py to something else may solve this problem but will generate more problems in other libraries as random.py is also imported in them.

Comment: Do you have a random.py of your own in your project?

Comment: No I Didnt Make Any File, I Just Made A New Venv From Anaconda And Only Created Main.py

Comment: Please copy the script and error message and post here as two code blocks. It makes it easier to see where the random.py is. And go back and fix that upper-casing of the first letter in each word as that makes your text harder to read.

Comment: "c:\Users\Syed M Tayyab\Desktop\VS Code ML\venv\Lib\random.py" is overriding the stdlib module "random"PylancereportShadowedImports

Comment: Looks like this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3751. Brief description: *"Pylance doesn't see your private python install as the environment in use for some reason"*

Comment: do you have some problem with your keyboard? every word starts with a CAPITAL

Comment: Can you try adding `"python.analysis.exclude": ["venv"],` to your `settings.json`

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Yes It Worked. The Error Is Gone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may be due to a recognition error caused by python created by `venv` being located in the workspace folder. You can try adding `"python.analysis.exclude": ["venv"],` to your `settings.json` to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below code snippet to json.settings is what fixed it on my system.

"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides" : {
"reportShadowedImports": "none"
}

More info in this GitHub thread
https://github.com/joedevivo/vscode-circuitpython/issues/106